# How to send email using Backbone and c# form

Tags: c#, backbone.js

I'm working on a very simple Backbone project which fetches some items from the database and displays it. This model will not be changed so there's not need to post this model back to the database. However, I have a form that when it's posted sends email to the recipients (which the backbone fetches from the database). I'm using C# as back-end for the project. How can I achieve this?

here's my html

```
<form name="bmsEmail" id="bmsEmail" role="form">
 <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="patientID" id="patientID" class="form-control" placeholder="Patient ID" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <textarea rows="11" name="message" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
     </div>
 </fieldset>
</form>

App.Views.EmailForm = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    id: 'emailForm',
    template: template('email-form'),

    events:{
        "submit form": "formSubmit"
    },

    formSubmit:function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    },

    render: function () {

        this.$el.append(this.template())
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: you are having trouble getting the form data to the server via backbone?  or sending an email from the asp.net server?  either way, google for those specifically and you will find plenty of answers.

Comment: @RobertLevy I googled but couldn't find an answer (or didn't search properly). Either way, the question I want to ask (I guess), is it possible to send email through backbone? or does it have to post to the asp.net server? And, if I don't have a collection or model for the email form, can I still post it? How? Or am I thinking this completely wrong?

Comment: No you can't send email from a web browser , need to follow the 2 steps I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to post the data that you want send to server and there use a SMTP ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) class from asp.net to send email.

Via browser is impossible because you need some configurations to send the mail.